# PHP MySQLi : Selecting multiple rows and displaying chosen column values for each

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to MySQLi and PHP and I am trying to select comments from my database, by matching a postid. It should select all rows that have that id, and display the name and value for each. But not working.

```
      // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      echo "<script>alert('dead!')</script>";
  }

    $get_comments = "SELECT * FROM 'articlecomments' WHERE 'commentpost' = 'post1' LIMIT 0 , 30";
  $check_comments = mysqli_query($conn, $get_comments);

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_comments) )  {
        echo "<script>alert('we have comments!');</script>

      <div class='comment-single'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3'>
            " . $check_comments['commentname'] . "
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-9'>
            " . $check_comments['commentvalue'] . "
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    ";

}
```

[image: Screenshot of database with the same query]
[image: database structure]

The connection establishes fine, as I could access other parts of the db in the same script. I suspect an issue with my query.

Thanks

Comment: remove the single quote before 'commentpost

Comment: @WebCode.ie ops thanks, fixed it. Does not appear to be the issue however

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tick for escaping columns not single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM `articlecomments`
WHERE `commentpost` = 'post1'
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$row['commentname']` and `$row['commentvalue']` to get the data from database.

```
echo "<script>alert('we have comments!');</script>

  <div class='comment-single'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-3'>
        " . $row['commentname'] . "
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-9'>
        " . $row['commentvalue'] . "
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong is your single quote around name of table:

```
$get_comments = "SELECT * FROM 'articlecomments' WHERE 'commentpost' = 'post1' LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Correct is:

```
$get_comments = "SELECT * FROM articlecomments WHERE commentpost = 'post1' LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Must write $row:

```
 " . $row['commentname'] . "
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-9'>
        " . $row['commentvalue'] . "
```